# How to make splitscreen in Direct2D?

Tags: c++, windows, directx, direct2d

Yesterday I asked a question on how to implement viewport in Direct2D. Now, I know that I could use device->SetTransform() but I also want to 'crop' objects in the window.

What I mean by crop is that so:

[image: before]

would become this:

[image: after]

Basically, I just want to add split screen to my application... Any help?

Comment: It's a weird thing but I can't find any reference to scissor for D2D.  It's a thing with D3D/OpenGL and so on.  Anyway you could do it with 2 layers - one for left side, one for right.

Comment: Oh nice idea! Thanks for help! Also, there is function PushAxisAlignedClip(). Now, Im wondering what should I use? I could start clipping rectangle(0,0,400,300) for left side, then draw everything with view1 transform. After that i could start clipping rectangle(400,300,800,600) then redraw everything with view2 transform... Or I could create 2 layers. To layer 1 I would apply view1 tranform and draw everything, and for layer 2 I would apply view2 transform and redraw everything... Now, Im not sure what to use! Is there any performance difference or something?

Comment: I think I'd probably go with two layers and no clip because it's cleaner.  However creating the extra surfaces a layer implies will use more video RAM.  Whether it's faster or slower really depends on the use case, how much you're drawing and so on.  I doubt you'll notice any difference to be honest.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks for help! I am currently implementing class View in my library (that obviously uses D2D) so this was helpful! Thaanks! :D

Comment: For this, I would go with AxisAlignedClip. As Robinson said, layers consume resources. Also they have some limitations, for example regarding antialiasing.